# why I am getting error in malloc ? I mean I was working when the height and width was equal but if the height is greater than width it getting stuck

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

When ever I tried to allocate memory it failed and I don't really know why? This is my school project in which I have to make a game to board and in board struct I have use double pointer of cell structure for player position and his letter now I can't able to allocate the memory and `draw_board` function just draws the board.

---

```
struct game {
    struct player *players[NUM_PLAYERS];
    int curr_player_num;
    struct board *the_board;
    struct letter_list *score_list;
};
struct player {
    char *name;
    char *color_name;
};
struct cell {
    struct player *owner;
    int letter;
};
struct board {
    struct cell **matrix;
    int width;
    int height;
};

void init_game() {
    struct game info;
    int i, j;
    printf("\nEnter the size of the board (row col)=> eg (5 5): ");
    scanf("%d %d", &info.the_board->height, &info.the_board->width);
    info.the_board->matrix = (struct cell **)malloc((info.the_board->height) * sizeof(struct cell *));
    if (info.the_board->matrix == NULL) {
        printf("out of memory!");
    }
    for (i = 0; i < info.the_board->height; i++) {
        printf("%d", info.the_board->width);
        info.the_board->matrix[i] = (struct cell *)malloc((info.the_board->width) * sizeof(struct cell)); // i think there is a error
        if (info.the_board->matrix[i] == NULL) {
            printf("Out of memeory");
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < info.the_board->height; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < info.the_board->width; j++) {
             info.the_board->matrix[i][j].owner = (void *)NULL;
             info.the_board->matrix[i][j].letter = EOF;
        }
    }
    draw_board(&info); //this will print the board
}

int main() {
    init_game();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `info.the_board->matrix = ...` Where was the `info.the_board` pointer initialized? Also, not every single struct member *has* to be a pointer. For example, unless you allow for a game with no board, or multiple games on the same board, `the_board` could be a `board` itself, not a pointer to one.

Answer (score 1):

The `board` structure pointed to by `info.the_board` has not been allocated, nor even initialized, dereferencing this pointer has undefined behavior. Furthermore, you must exit the function when you detect an allocation error, otherwise you will crash in the subsequent code.

```
int init_game() {
    struct game info = { 0 };
    int i, j;

    info.board = calloc(sizeof(*info.board), 1);
    if (info.board == NULL) {
        printf("cannot allocate board\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("\nEnter the size of the board (row col)=> eg (5 5): ");
    scanf("%d %d", &info.the_board->height, &info.the_board->width);
    info.the_board->matrix = calloc(info.the_board->height, sizeof(struct cell *));
    if (info.the_board->matrix == NULL) {
        printf("out of memory!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < info.the_board->height; i++) {
        //printf("%d", info.the_board->width);  //debug
        info.the_board->matrix[i] = calloc(info.the_board->width, sizeof(struct cell));
        if (info.the_board->matrix[i] == NULL) {
            printf("Out of memory\n");
            // free previous matrix rows
            while (i --> 0) {
                free(info.the_board->matrix[i])
            }
            return -1;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < info.the_board->height; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < info.the_board->width; j++) {
             info.the_board->matrix[i][j].owner = NULL;
             info.the_board->matrix[i][j].letter = EOF;
        }
    }
    draw_board(&info); //this will print the board
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks alot this solved my problem can you share some resources where i can learn more about this stuff